# Can I use Python indentation style for Java or C++?

Tags: c++, python, eclipse-plugin, notepad++, indentation

I like Python style because it's easy to read and write. Makes the code shorter avoiding unnecessary characters like ';' or '{}'. However, I need to use Java and C++ at work.

I would like to know if there is a way to use Python indentation rules with those languages. Maybe exists a plugin for Notepad++ or Eclipse that would do something like this:

When I open a file.java, changes the Java indentation rules and formats the file with Python rules so it's easier for me to read. When I edit and save it, the plugin adds all the ';' and '{}' again for the JVM to understand.

I guess that some of you will think that this is an awful idea but I just want to try it. In my opinion, learning a new language is interesting but learning new indentation rules is just boring and useless.

Comment: Python is the only language(on the top of my mind) with indentation RULES

Comment: @KarthikT Haskell does as well. And most brace-delimited languages have a few dialects of culturally enforced indentation rules (certainly most large projects have their preferred indentation style).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it, but it's probably a bad idea. Sticking to the language conventions lets you share code with other developers. Switching braces with tabs would confuse any C professional who'd like to patch your code.

Having that said, [nobraces](http://blog.brush.co.nz/2007/09/nobraces/) converts tabs to braces:

> Anyway, I still use C quite a bit for embedded programming contracts,
>   and Tim Hatch’s pybraces inspired me to write an analogue for C that
>   gives you Python-style indentation for C.

See also [How Python affected my C/C++ brace style](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/14/how-python-affected-my-cc-brace-style/) By Eli Bendersky.

Comment: Thanks for the links, very interesting. Just clarify that I don't want to save my code in any different format, just visualise it to read and write. The code would still be exactly the same for any other developer reading my code.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know of any such plugins, there is not necessarily a sane way to do this.
There are instances, where a loop without a body makes sense in cpp. The semicolon makes the intention clear, without it it might look like a missing identation. I think you should just use the extra characters, which if you get used to them increase readability, especially if you have an editor that highlights matching (corresponding opening and closing) braces/brackets.

SInce Java and cpp let you indent your code anyway you want, you can still use identation similar to that in python.

For completness two example of loops without a body in c:

Waiting for a special microcontroller register to switch:

```
while(magicRegister==1);
```

Copying c style string (carefull this is errorprone (overflow)):

```
while(*(strptrcpy++) = *(strptrsrc++));
```

Comment: You don't really put the semicolon on the same line, do you?  (If you do, it's guaranteed that anyone reading your code will miss it, and think that the loop controls the following line.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Actually I personally do, I use identation as well and I _always_ use opening and closing braces if there is a body even if it has just one line of code. I guess this is a matter of taste so to speak. But I see why one might want to put the semicolon on a new line.